# reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

What I am trying to achieve:

Saving a Flux with any spring data (elastic / mongo / cassandra) reactive repository.

What I tried:

```
public Flux<Foo> issue() {
        Sinks.Many<Foo> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        kafkaReceiver.receive()
                .map(message -> convertMesageToFoo(message)
                )
                .bufferTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofMillis(500))//tried many values for maxSize and maxTime
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<>() {
                    private Subscription subscription;
                    volatile boolean upstreamComplete = false;

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                        this.subscription = subscription;
                        subscription.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Foo> foos) {
                        reactiveElasticRepository.saveAll(foos)
                                .map(sink::tryEmitNext)
                                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                                    if (!upstreamComplete) {
                                        subscription.request(1);
                                    } else {
                                        sink.tryEmitComplete();
                                    }
                                })
                                .subscribe();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        System.err.println("I am able to reproduce this issue 100% " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                        subscription.cancel();
                        sink.tryEmitError(throwable);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        upstreamComplete = true;
                    }
                });

        return sink.asFlux();
    }
```

Issue:

Reproducible 100%, I am observing this error:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferTimeout$BufferTimeoutSubscriber.flushCallback(FluxBufferTimeout.java:227)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferTimeout$BufferTimeoutSubscriber.lambda$new$0(FluxBufferTimeout.java:158)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Question:

How to workaround or fix this issue?

Comment: These issues may be relevant: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2942 and https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3106. BR

Comment: Hey @RoarS. thank you for your comment here. Do you know if there is an alternative, maybe using other reactive operators, which will help mitigate / workaround this issue?